# Storing a bear roast after cooking in a crockpot

Tags: storage-method, crockpot, roast, bear

How do you store a bear roast after cooking it in a crockpot until you're ready to eat it?

It was done at 8:30am and I plan to eat it around 6:00pm. It was cooked in beef broth.

Comment: Need a few more details. How long after cooking do you plan on eat it? Hours ? Days ? Weeks ? Was it cooked in liquid (braised) ?

Comment: ...  E.g. Hours: keep in the slow cooker on low; days: fridge; weeks+: freezer

Comment: It was done at 8:30am and I planned to eat it around 6:00pm. Yes, it was cooked in beef broth.

Comment: I agree w/ Chris H ... but I'd have used warm for the crockpot if I knew it'd hold the temperature above 140°F

Answer (score 3):

If your crock has a warm that you can trust is above 140 F but not so hot to cook it down then you can leave it in the crock.  Otherwise you need to get it under 40 F.

A better option would have been to start it at a time so that it finished at 6 PM.
Why not just start it 8:30 AM?

If you are going to cool then remove from the crock pot as that is a lot of heat to put in a refrigerator.

Comment: If you're not going to separate it from the liquid like Adi recommended, I would still recommend heating them separately.  (I'd link to the question about re-heating a roast in a crock pot, but I can't find it).  But I'd also recommend separating them, as it adds additional surface area to help with cooling things.  (also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3970/67 )

Comment: @Joe The stated question is "after cooking".  I sure would not recommend crock dry (even if it was a reheat).   Nor would I recommend refrigerate separately.

Answer (score 1):

Upon completion of the cooking, let it cool down to room temperature. Remove excess liquids and store separately. Cover the roast in tinfoil and store in the fridge. Consume preferably within two days for animal proteins.(Freeze for max 3 months)
Hope this helps :)